# Connect Apache Cordova to Azure Mobile Services disabled in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services, apache-cordova

How do I enable connecting `Azure Mobile Services` for an **Apache Cordova** app in Visual Studio 2015?

1. I started Visual Studio 2015
2. Clicked New Project, Java Script -> Blank App (Apache Cordova)
3. Right clicked on the project in Solution Explorer -> Add -> Connected Service
4. Click Azure Mobile Service

RESULT: Configure button is disabled with a message when hovered which says "This service is not supported on the current project type"

I tried the following:

- Looked for visual studio updates and found one for Azure Mobile Services, but didn't solve the problem
- Starting with one of the JS samples Microsoft provides and the same problem happens (https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples)

Visual Studio version info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00079
Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-80000-00000-AA370
Visual Basic 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA370
Visual C# 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA370
Visual C++ 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA370
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   00322-80000-00000-AA370
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools   14.0.20711.0
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
Common Azure Tools   1.6
GenerateUnitTest   1.0
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2   Build 103.0.20150818.200216
Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service   2.0.2600.0
Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.2600.0
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Tools   2.7
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.7.30818.1601
Microsoft Code Digger   0.9
Microsoft.Pex.VisualStudio   1.0
NuGet Package Manager   3.2.0
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.23309.00 d14oob
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use a connected service with Cordova code right now.  However, check out https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-services-cordova - this is the Azure Mobile Services Cordova SDK.  The README has links to documentation and forums for assistance.

Comment: Following up - we are not seeing this in the RTM Visual Studio code.  The suggestion is to use the VS Installer and repair the VS installation.  Can you try that?